# org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Unknown version specified for initialization: 3.1.0

Tags: hive

I finally resolved so many issues, just to run into the following issue. I have absolutely no idea why this error is occurring at the moment. If someone can spot the issue here, please let me know.

```
$ schematool -dbType derby -initSchema
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/apache/apache-hive-3.1.3-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/hadoop-3.3.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Metastore connection URL:        jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true
Metastore Connection Driver :    org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
Metastore connection User:       APP
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Failed to get schema version.
Underlying cause: java.sql.SQLException : Failed to start database 'metastore_db' with class loader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6a5fc7f7, see the next exception for details.
SQL Error code: 40000
Use --verbose for detailed stacktrace.
*** schemaTool failed ***
```

With **--verbose**:

```
$ schematool -dbType derby -initSchema --verbose
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/apache/apache-hive-3.1.3-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/hadoop-3.3.4/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Metastore connection URL:        jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/metastore_db;create=true
Metastore Connection Driver :    org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
Metastore connection User:       APP
Starting metastore schema initialization to 3.1.0
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Unknown version specified for initialization: 3.1.0
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Unknown version specified for initialization: 3.1.0
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreSchemaInfo.generateInitFileName(MetaStoreSchemaInfo.java:137)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:585)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:567)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.main(HiveSchemaTool.java:1517)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
*** schemaTool failed ***
```

Comment: I feel like it might be easier to setup mysql or Postgres metastore rather than rely on Derby

Comment: @OneCricketeer, I am using Derby.

Comment: I can see that. I was simply suggesting that the others would cause less errors. Plus, even Hive documentation says Derby is not intended to be used long term, or in a production installation. In any case, the "Unknown version" refers to the Schema files in Hive source code, where there isn't any 3.x files - https://github.com/apache/hive/tree/master/metastore/scripts/upgrade/derby

Comment: @AlixBlaine  if you are interested in dockerized version then I have created one here with latest hive and tez. hub.docker.com/repository/docker/raiddocker/apache_hive/general Let me know if it works in Docker for Windows